# Огромное число в с++

Tags: c++, математика

В университете дали задачку на подсёт суммы всех n-значных символов. Например: n = 3 (сумма от 100 до 999). Подсчёт я делаю при помощи формулы на cуммы арифметической прогресии: ((pow(10, n - 1) + (10, n) - 1) * (pow(10, n) - 1 + pow(10, n - 1) + 1))

Вопрос: при вводе n = 80 итоговый результат получиться на более чем 250 символов, можно-ли вывести подсчёт без использывания сторонних библиотек. (Язык только С++)

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Вывести сумму всех n-значных чисел. Например: n = 3 (сумма чисел от 100 до 999). При вводе n = 80 вывести на экран сумму, которая составит больше 150-ти символов

Comment: Такие вещи через `pow` не считают...

Comment: Никак. В С++ нет ни одного типа который бы уместил себе число с 80 знаками. Здесь простая арифметическая прогрессия, решается в одну формулу. С библиотекой очень просто.

Comment: Или самому создать класс, для больших чисел.

Comment: Или зная свойства результирующей суммы, можно написать алгоритм выводящий результат, но здесь вывод будет строковый. Т.е. результат будет храниться в строке, которую будем выводить. Алгоритм вам уже рассказали в ответе.

Answer (score 2):

Сумма двузначных чисел равна 4905. Трехзначных - 494550.

Дальше сумма имеет такой вид: 494 *(9)* 55 *(0)*, где количество 9 равно n-3, а количество 0 равно n-2.

Т.е. например в сумме девятизначных чисел (n = 9) девяток будет 6, а нулей 7: 494999999550000000.

Comment: При всем уважении, 4949999955000000... https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5Bi%2C%7Bi%2C10000000%2C99999999%7D%5D

Comment: @Harry ай, да. Ошибся в степенях. 10**3 это же четырехзначное :)) итд.

Comment: Благодарю за пояснение! 29 задач сделал, эту пытался вместо логического рассуждения арифметикой решить =)

Answer (score 1):

Если не ошибся, то

```
int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    if (n <= 2) { cout << "Такие вещи считают в уме!"; return 0; }
    cout << 494;
    for(int i = 0; i < n-3; ++i) cout << 9;
    cout << 55;
    for(int i = 0; i < n-2; ++i) cout << 0;
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: для двузначных неправильно же

Comment: @Эникейщик Так устроит? :)